# How to redirect using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I am working on moving an IIS server website onto an AWS Load balancer. I am trying to figure out how to Manipulate a web link in Apache. My team and I are currently using IIRF to redirect the link in our IIS server, but I am trying to figure out how to manipulate a link; I want to change the hostname from lets say for example `this.link.com` to `mysite.link.edu`.

After searching online, I found that this should be possible using `mod_rewrite`, but my programming skills are not very sharp. I read [Apache's page on mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but it is still unclear to me how this works.

I installed Amazon Linux (Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.03) with Apache. I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) on how to configure it, but the command `a2enmod` is not available on my system, and neither is the service `apache2`;

```
sudo service apache2 restart
apache2: unrecognized service
```

---

I am new to Apache and fairly new to Linux server management, so I don't know how to continue from here.

How can I configure Apache to redirect requests to another hostname?

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be stabbing around in the dark. `mod_rewrite` has never been a CLI command. There's no such thing as an AWS Multi-AZ EC2 instance - they exist for RDS, but you don't get a CLI on those, only MySQL access. I also really don't think `sudo service apache2 restart` is giving you that error. Isn't the service `httpd` in Amazon Linux anyways?

Comment: Apache on Amazon Linux AMI has mod_rewrite enabled by default; you don't need to enable it. `apt-get` is only included in Debian-based distributions, you should use `yum` instead, as AMI is RHEL-based. I cannot answer your question, because it is very unclear what you are trying to do and what you already tried. As ceejayoz has already illustrated, your question contains many factual inaccuracies.

Comment: Walk away from the computer now - this is clearly something you're not up to doing.

Comment: Based on ceejayoz comment I looks like I am definitely taking stabs in the dark... My team and I are currently using IIRF to redirect the link in our IIS server but I am trying to figure out how to manipulate a link to change the name from lets say for example this.link.com to mysite.link.edu. I read online that this could be done using mod_rewrite but programming skills are not very sharp and get confused when I read pages like this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html. Thus, I am here searching for some help. Please, let me know if there is anything else I can do to help

Comment: Did you look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost; I think that is pretty much what you want. I checked out your profile, it looks like you're active on StackOverflow; you asked this question there before (and got sent here). I want to let you know that ServerFault has higher expectations of you when it comes to doing your homework before you post. Since you have some rep on StackOverflow, i'll use some of my time to try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using CentOS, or another RHEL-derivative, like Amazon Linux.

The commands that are failing for you, are failing because they are specific to Debian derivatives, which you are clearly not using. In RHEL, there is no need to enable mod_rewrite in Apache, it comes with mod_rewrite enabled.

All you really need to do, is to create a file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, say `redirect.conf`, and put in these contents (taken from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost)):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName undesired.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com

    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect everything from `undesired.example.com`, `example.com` and `notthis.example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Then you run

```
service httpd restart
```

This differs from `service apache2 restart`, which is for Debian.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Jorn! And thanks for the extra notes.